# Update query not taking effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to manually update the table `umbracoNode` in MSSql now when I try to query the node that I want to update using the below command

```
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
      umbracoNode
  WHERE
      nodeObjectType = '366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B029728';
```

I get 30 results. Now when I try to update it using this command

```
Update umbracoNode 
set nodeObjectType = '366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B02972899' 
where nodeObjectType='366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B029728'
and id < '11335'
```

Now it says 25 rows affected which is what I expected. Now when I try to query again using the select query above it still return the same record. I was expecting to only see 5 records and not 30

Update:
Here is the table definition

[image]

Comment: Can you share your table definition? At least the fields involved.

Comment: What is `nodeObjectType`'s type? I suspect it's a fixed-length char field instead of a GUID (which wouldn't accept the new value anyway).

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera updated my question

Comment: See @allmhuran answer. A unique identifier field is not a varchar.

Answer (score 6):

nodeObjectType must be a `uniqueidentifier`, which is silently truncating:

```
 declare @g uniqueidentifier
 set @g = '366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B029728'
 set @g = '366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B02972899'
 select @g -- returns 366E63B9-880F-4E13-A61C-98069B029728
```